# Pycharm autocomplete not working for some packages

Tags: python, pycharm

I never really used pycharm before, but have used other JetBrains products and I expect the autocomplete to work.

When used on modules likes `tkinter`, after writing `tk.` I'll get the autocomplete, with methods like `tk.Tk()`. However, when used on another module (also included in python by default), ctypes, I don't get that kind of autocomplete.

If I start writing `windll`, I'll get an autocomplete for it, but won't get one after that, so if I write `windll.user32`, which is a perfectly valid code that runs just fine, I have no way of knowing whether `user32` exists or not, ctrl+space shows nothing.

The variable is then successfully created, but using `myVar.` shows nothing. I'm using anaconda (but also tried on default python) and have the interpreter setup just fine.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm uses static analysis to provide completions, inspections, code insight features and so on.

Static analysis means reading project files and extracting knowledge from expected definitions of classes, function, attributes.

Due to dynamic nature of Python, some of these members could be declared dynamically via assignments, functions with side-effects, etc.

This is a possible reason why there could be no completion in some cases.